# gdb of simple hello world program not working as expected on Mac 10.13.6

Tags: gdb

I was just intending to explore the features of gdb by following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PorfLSr3DDI&t=212s

While trying to replicate the steps as in the movie above, I got slightly different output:

When I ran

```
gdb a.out
```

, I got this:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.2.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html> 5 user  staff   160 May  8 22:46 .
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.wxr-xr-x    1 user  staff  8432 May  8 22:46 a.out
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.world.c
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
Users-MBP:codecompre_tooltest user$ 
For help, type "help".ooltest user$ 
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from a.out...
warning: dsym file UUID doesn't match the one in /Users/user/Documents/codecompre_tooltest/a.out
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x100000f04
Starting program: /Users/user/Documents/codecompre_tooltest/a.out 
[New Thread 0x1703 of process 1645]
[New Thread 0x1903 of process 1645]
[New Thread 0x1a03 of process 1645]

[3]+  Stopped                 gdb a.out
```

Why is this so, and how can I solve this?

NOTE: I have followed all the steps in:

1. http://panks.me/posts/2013/11/install-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks-from-source/
2. https://gist.github.com/kpy3/27014703672ad6d54c00dfc06e45f1ae